# My code keeps printing " (double quotes) from nowhere

Tags: c

I didnt even ask to print double quotes. But it keeps printing after I put an input starting with D. When i put 'C', the output is normal. Example:

input >
D

2

9

egdqncekq

B4 i put "egdqncekq", the program prints a double quotes for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char cd, m;
  int size, i, disp, m1;
 
  cd=getchar();
  scanf("%d", &disp);
  scanf("%d", &size);
 
  switch(cd)
  {
  case 'C':
  for(i=0; i<=size; i++)
  {
    m=getchar();
    m1=m+disp;
    if(m1>122)
    {
      m1=m1-26;
    }
    printf("%c", m1);
  }
  break;

  case 'D':
    for(i=0; i<=size; i++)
    {
      m=getchar();
      m1=m-disp;
      if(m1<97)
      {
        m1=m1+26;
      }
      printf("%c", m1);
    } 
    break;
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you "seeing" the double quotes? It doesn't show in your output. At least it's not clear how you are reaching the conclusion that it is printing those.

Comment: @kaylum
[link](https://i.imgur.com/6ZfU4p1.png)
[link](https://i.imgur.com/baioXnC.png)

Its always after i ask the value of the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the second `scanf` there's a newline character (ASCII 10) left in the input buffer.  That newline gets picked up by the `getchar` function in each of the loops.

In the "C" case, 2 is added to this value which results in 12.  This is the ASCII form feed character which prints as an extra newline.

In the "D" case, 2 is subtracted from this value resulting in 8.  This value is less than 97 so 26 is added resulting in 34, which is the ASCII code for the `"` character which then gets printed.

Before entering the `switch` statement, you should call `getchar` in a loop until you see a newline.  That will flush out the input buffer.

Comment: Alternatively, you could call `fgets` to read entire lines of input and use `sscanf` to read from the line buffer.